# How would I get this routing to work between the two subnets? Unsure if i am over-complicating my network

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking

I am attempting to operate 2 subnets, the first subnet on range `192.168.0.0/24` is free to access anything it wants, including machines on the second subnet. the second subnet on range `10.0.0.0/24` is restricted to *only* being able to access the outside world. I do not want machines with a source within `10.0.0.0/24` to be able to access machines in the `192.168.0.0/24` range but i do want it to be able to go outside.

On top of this, in the `192.168.0.0/24` range i also want 2 gateways, the first being the default gateway (currently in the form of an Ubuntu VM) which routes traffic via a vpn, its address is `192.168.0.250` and the second gateway (which is the internet-facing TP-Link wireless router) at `192.168.0.1` (also the DHCP & DNS server for the `192.168.0.0/24` range)

I also have a third gateway for bridging the two subnets, another Ubuntu VM with 2 NICS, the first being `192.168.0.251` and the second being `10.0.0.1`

Now that I have explained the network i want, here is my setup and what i am experiencing:

**Ubuntu VM on 192.168.0.250**

the route table on `192.168.0.250` looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        192.168.0.251   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.1        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
.               192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

I add the routes via

```
 ip rule add from 192.168.0.0/24 table default
 ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.251
 ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/24 table sandboxgateway
 ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table sandboxgateway
```

If i remove the two `sandboxgateway` lines i can access `10.0.0.1` but anything in the `10.0.0.X` range is accessing the internet through the VPN, which is not what i want.
and its iptable looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**Ubuntu VM on 192.168.0.251/10.0.0.1**

the route table on `192.168.0.251(eth0)/10.0.0.1(eth1)` looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.250   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and its iptable looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          192.168.0.0/24

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**The issue**

The issue I am having is that while my machine at `192.168.0.2` can access the outside world either via `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.0.250` as its gateway, as can my machine at `10.0.0.10` access the outside world without accessing anything at `192.168.0.X`, my machine at `192.168.0.2` cannot access either `10.0.0.1` or `10.0.0.10`, and a `tracert` from the windows command prompt results in

Tracing route to 10.0.0.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.250
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Why is `192.168.0.250` not routing to `192.168.0.251`??

Apologies if i have included too much or too little information, please ask if any additional details are needed to answer this question.

Comment: First of all edit /etc/sysctl.conf. Uncomment (or edit) the line there with: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: This allows packet forwarding between two NICs (after reboot)

Comment: @AntonMakovetsky that has already been done, as i said 10.0.0.X can access the outside world

Comment: By 192.168.0.0/8 you must really mean 192.168.0.0/24, right?

Comment: @joeqwerty When i wrote the question they were actually set to /8, i realised that mistake and changed them all to /24, ill update the question to reflect that. It's still suffering from the same issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

The iptables packetfilter drops the responses of the 10.0.0.0/8 ips to the 192.168.0.0/8 IPs. Add a rule to allow packets from 10.0 to 192.168 that are already established, before the DROP rule:

```
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

That should do the trick. If not, remove the DROP rule to check if that is really the origin of the problem. If so, you might have to build a more sophisticated ruleset.

Comment: aha yes this seems pretty obvious if it is the cause, i shall try this now.

Comment: OK, adding that did not help, however removing the previous one and removing the `ip  rule add from 192.168.0.0/8 table default`,
 `ip rule add from 10.0.0.0/8 table sandboxgateway`,`ip route add default` & `via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table sandboxgateway` commands allows `192.168.0.2` to ping `10.0.0.10`. I will experiment some more based on this. This issue with this is obviously that `10.0.0.10` can access `192.168.0.0/8` and its tunneling through the VPN, both undesirable.